# How to increase UPDATE speed, java connected to sql or using cursor

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, cursor, sql-update

I am trying to increase the speed of UPDATE using jdbc. There are 300000 rows, and I want to change the column of X of each row to 5. But I needed to make them sorted according to their primary keys. Because there are 400000 rows and I want to change 300000 rows from top.

Here is what I did so far:

First I tried to send every query when it is created using prepared stetament

```
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date (time)));

    for(int i=number-1; i>=0; i--){
        try{
            pStmt.setInt(1, (int) hashMap.get(i));
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            result = pStmt.executeUpdate();
            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            totalTime += time;
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date (System.currentTimeMillis())));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

But it took many time. About 900 sec.

Then I tried to add them to a batch, using addBatch()

java.sql.PreparedStatement pStmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(query);

```
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
            pStmt2.setInt(1, (int) hashMap.get(i));
            pStmt2.addBatch();
    }

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date (time)));

    pStmt2.executeBatch();

    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date (System.currentTimeMillis())));
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
```

It was better but not that better. Only there was a 50 sec. difference.

And I tried to execute blocks. That means: there are 300000 rows and for every 30000 I added queries to a batch, then execute them. And I did this 10 times.

It was much better but still too slow. It was about 800 sec

Then I want to do this process with small rows such as 10000, in one line:

Update tabel1 set outcome=3 order by key DESC limit 10000.

which takes first 10000 rows, and change every outcome cells of them. This took about 24sec. This time is so close to other tests when I tried themn with 10000 rows.

Then I tried to do this process with using cursor. Updating 10000 rows only took 4 secs.

The result is interesting.

But I want to update them using jdbc. Is there any other ways to do it? And why cursor is too speed?

Comment: Consider editing your question, and pasting in the SQL DDL that creates the table you're trying to update. Also include the queries you're trying to execute.

Comment: making all UPDATEs inside a single transaction is allways a boost, so begin a transaction, do all updates and finaly commit them. But ... this can cause locks to other users :(